# How to get Access Token for Client Based Application for Zoho API?

Tags: access-token, zoho

Does this mean Zoho API documentations are wrong?
I'm following the "[client based applications](https://www.zoho.com/accounts/protocol/oauth/js-apps/access-token.html)" as my app is a ReactJS based app. Unfortuantely im getting a fetch failed type of error when trying to request an authentication token using **response_type = token**.

Very frustrating indeed.

What is the proper way to get an auth token for ReactJs apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by chrome(or firefox)

Get format (make single line)

```
https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth?
client_id={your client id}&
response_type=token&
scope=AaaServer.profile.Read&
redirect_uri={your app redirect URI}
```

This is steps

1. Get **client_id** and **redirect_uri** from my Zoho Setting

```
https://api-console.zoho.com/
```

[image]
[image]

2. Make single line string with upper format
   put that string and enter from Chrome
   The client id and redirect URI should be match your App settings.

[image]

Click the Accept button with checked Grant access checkbox

[image]

Will get  the access token at address editor in Chrome

[image]

3. Get new access token with this format

```
http://localhost:3000/#&
access_token={get-new-access-token}&
expires_in=3600&
location=us&
api_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zohoapis.com&
granted_for_session=true
```

You can make your React app for getting access token with this steps.

Comment: im doing this exact thing. i get this error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: I try again in Today, it works too. Can you try after new App setting instead existing App setting? I updated my answer to add setting API and access token format.

Comment: Upon network inspection i see the http code error: 302.

Comment: Error 302 means redirection  error, so your app settings redirect URL was not match in your query.

Comment: I just double checked and triple checked the redirect_url. It is exactly how it appears in the console (copy and pasted).

Comment: If i make the request directly from a browser, then it works exactly the way you describe it. But if I make the request thru my javascript code (via fetch API), then i get the 302.

Comment: In step 2, user needs to click the accept bottom by browser. it can't skip it. It means no way to access-token java-script only code.

Comment: Yes, i did click the Accept button in the browser. Then it redirects me to the redirect_uri. But then, where is the access token?

Comment: In the Step 3, you need s to parsing the access_token part. Can you add your Java Script code in the question, I will try to parse it.